Is there a way to pass a throwing property as an argument to a function, or to an initializer? Swift
I have a struct Object, that has a throwing computed property. It is static, but that does not matter.
struct Object {
    
    static var list: [Self] {
        get throws {
            // implementation here
        }
    }
}

I need to pass the property to an initializer of a View, which would convert to a Result. I do not want to convert it before passing. I want the initializer to do that job. Is that possible?
struct CustomView: View {
    
    private let result: Result<[Object], Error>
    
    init(_ prop: // accepting a throwing property of type array of Object) { // code here // }
    
    var body: some View {}
}

I want to instantiate a CustomView like this: CustomView(Object.list). Is this possible?
Alternatively, I would like to see if I can "extend" a throwing property, any throwing property (generics), so that it would have a .result computed property. In that case, the CustomView will take a result as argument, and I would call it like this: CustomView(Object.list.result). Possible?
Thank you.
I tried sending argument like () throws -> [Object], but it only works if a use try at the calling site.

This is not possible. You always need to write try, by design. The idea is that every point where an error can occur should be clearly marked. Why don't you want to write try?

Have you considered changing the declaration of list?

Why do you need to pass that property, since it's static you can access it easily within the init or if you still want to have a parameter to the init you can access it before creating the view.
